# Objective C newbie

Tags: objective-c

I'm taking a class and we're working on a Calculator program.  My background is in C++.  I am taking a RPN calculator entry of 3 enter sqrt and need to display it as sqrt(3) in my descriptionOfProgram method, which is new, including associated property below.  Here's the class so far. Search for "xcode" to find my issues.  Any ideas?  I'm not very good at the basic objective c classes, but I'm trying to learn.  Here's a summary:

1. it's complaining about my boolean.  I'm not sure why. I did this in a different class and it worked fine.
2. it's looking for a {  I don't see it
3. it doesn't like my use of the key.  I'm unclear on how to get the key's contents I think is the problem.
4. It wants ] but I'm not seeing why
5. skipped
6. It expected } at @end

Hope you can help!  Thanks!

```
//
//  CalculatorBrain.m
//  Calculator
//
//  Created by Michele Cleary on 2/25/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorBrain()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray  *programStack;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *testVariable;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL numberHandledNextOperation;
- (double) convertRadianToDegree: (double) radian;
@end

@implementation CalculatorBrain

@synthesize programStack = _programStack;
@synthesize testVariable = _testVariable;
@synthesize numberHandledNextOperation = _numberHandledNextOperation;


- (NSMutableArray *)programStack
{
    if (_programStack == nil) _programStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return _programStack;
}
//- (void)setOperandStack:(NSMutableArray *)operandStack
//{
//    _operandStack = operandStack;
//}



- (void)pushOperand:(double)operand
{
    [self.programStack addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand]];   
}

- (double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation
{
    [self.programStack addObject:operation];
    return[CalculatorBrain runProgram:self.program];

}

- (id)program
{
    return [self.programStack copy];
}

+ (NSString *)descriptionOfProgram:(id)program
{
    self.numberHandledNextOperation = NO;  //1. this is a problem with xcode: member reference type struct objc_class * is a pointer; maybe you meant to use ->

    NSMutableSet * displayDescrip = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

    for(id foundItemKey in program)
    {
        if ([foundItemKey isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            //operator or variable
        {
            if ([foundItemKey isEqualToString:@"sin"]&&(!self.numberHandledNextOperation)) 
            { //2. xcode says To match this {. 
                NSObject *nextObj = [program objectForKey:(foundItemKey+1);  //3. xcode doesn't like this: arithmetic on pointer to interface id which is not a constant size in non-fragile ABI
                //[displayDescrip addObject:foundItemKey];
            }
            else if ([foundItemKey isEqualToString:@"cos"]) 
            {
                //[displayDescrip addObject:foundItemKey];
            }
            else if ([foundItemKey isEqualToString:@"sqrt"])
            {
                //[displayDescrip addObject:foundItemKey];
            }
            else if ([foundItemKey isEqualToString:@"Ï€"]) 
            {
                //[displayDescrip addObject:foundItemKey];
            }
            else if (![CalculatorBrain isOperationName:foundItemKey]) 
            {
            //variable

                //[displayDescrip addObject:foundItemkey];
            }
            else if (foundItemKey isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class])  //4. xcode expected ]
            {
                //number
                //if next object is operation
                if(isOperation([program objectForKey:(foundItemKey+1))) 
                {
                    numberHandledNextOperation = YES;
                    if(isOperationSpecial([program objectForKey:(foundItemKey+1)))
                    { //sin or cos or sqrt need parentheses
                        //[displayDescrip addObject:(foundItemKey+1)];
                        //[displayDescrip addObject:@"("];
                        //[displayDescrip addObject:foundItemKey];
                        //[displayDescrip addObject:@")"];
                    }
                    else 
                    { //regular operation + - / *
                    //[displayDescrip addObject:(foundItemKey+1)];
                    //[displayDescrip addObject:(foundItemKey)];
                    }
                    numberHandledNextOperation = YES;
                 } //if
            } //else if

        } //if
    } //for
    //not sure if I need this next thing
    //NSSet * returnedVarNames = [varNames copy];
    //return returnedVarNames;
    return @"implement this in Assignment 2";
}

+ (double)runProgram:(id)program
{
    NSMutableArray *stack;
    if ([program isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        stack = [program mutableCopy];
    }
    return [self popOperandOffStack:stack];
}

+ (double)runProgram:(id)program usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary *)variableValues
{
    NSMutableArray *stack;
    if ([program isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        stack = [program mutableCopy];
    }

    if(variableValues)
    {
        int numItemsDisplayed = [stack count];
        for (int count = 0; count < numItemsDisplayed; count++) 
        {
            id foundItem = [stack objectAtIndex:count];
            if ([foundItem isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            {
                NSString * var = [variableValues objectForKey:foundItem];
                if(var)
                {
                   [stack replaceObjectAtIndex:count withObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[var doubleValue]]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return [self popOperandOffStack:stack];
}

+ (double)popOperandOffStack:(NSMutableArray *)stack
{
    double result = 0;

    id topOfStack = [stack lastObject];
    if (topOfStack) [stack removeLastObject];

    if([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]){ //number
        result = [topOfStack doubleValue];
    }
    else if ([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){ //string operation
        NSString *operation = topOfStack;
        if ([operation isEqualToString:@"+"]) {
            result = [self popOperandOffStack:stack] + [self popOperandOffStack:stack];
        }else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"*"]) {
            result = [self popOperandOffStack:stack] * [self popOperandOffStack:stack];    
        }else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"/"]) {
            double divisor = [self popOperandOffStack:stack];
            if (divisor) 
                result = [self popOperandOffStack:stack] / divisor;    
        }else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"-"]) {
            double subtrahend = [self popOperandOffStack:stack];
            result = [self popOperandOffStack:stack] - subtrahend;    
        }else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"sin"]) {
            result = result = (sin([self popOperandOffStack:stack])); //(sin([self convertRadianToDegree:[self popOperandOffStack:stack]]));    
        }else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"cos"]) {
            result = (cos([self popOperandOffStack:stack]));    
        }else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"sqrt"]) {
            result = (sqrt([self popOperandOffStack:stack]));    
        }else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"π"]) {
            result = M_PI;    
        }else{
            result = 0;
        }


    }

    return result;
}

+ (NSSet *)variablesUsedInProgram:(id)program
{
    NSMutableSet * varNames = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

    for(id foundItem in program)
    {
       if ([foundItem isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
       {
           if (![CalculatorBrain isOperationName:foundItem])
           {
               [varNames addObject:foundItem];
           }
       }
    }
    NSSet * returnedVarNames = [varNames copy];
    return returnedVarNames;
}

+ (BOOL)isOperationName:(NSString *)foundItem
{
    NSSet *myOperationSet = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"sqrt", @"sin", @"cos", @"π", @"+", @"-", @"*", @"/", nil];
    return([myOperationSet containsObject:(foundItem)]);
}

- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"stack = %@", self.programStack];
}

-(double) convertRadianToDegree: (double) radian;
{
    return M_PI*2*radian/360;
}

@end  //6. xcode expected }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The site works best when members post complete questions that have specific answers. Have you tried to search Stack Overflow for the error or warning you're seeing?

Answer (score 3):

```
+ (NSString *)descriptionOfProgram:(id)program
```

Do you actually want `descriptionOfProgram` a class `+` method ? If yes, it is more like a static method in C++. It doesn't belong to any particular instance of a class. There is no hidden parameter of constant pointer to the current instance is passed.

Comment: Actually, using `self` _is_ allowed in class methods, it just doesn't point to an instance of the class, but to the class itself.